# Exibir dialog com primefaces ao clicar em uma emptyMessage de um p:autoComplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, primefaces, jsf-2.2

Bom estou utilizando Primefaces tenho um campo p:autoComplete para buscar Funcionários, gostaria que quando digitasse um nome e não fosse encontrado nenhum resultado ele exibisse a mensagem de "Nenhum funcionário encontrado, click **aqui** para cadastrar" (exibir a mensagem já faço utilizando o atributo emptyMessage do autocomplete), e quando clicasse no **aqui** fosse exibido um dialog. Tentei utilizando AJAX porém sem sucesso acredito que terei de usar JavasCript ou jQuery, se puderem me ajudar agradeço desde já!!
A seguir o código do autoComplete:

```
<p:autoComplete value="#{bean.funcionario}"
    completeMethod="#{bean.completarFuncionario}" var="funcionario"
    itemLabel="#{funcionario.nome}" itemValue="#{funcionario}"
    emptyMessage="Nenhum funcionário encontrado click aqui para cadastrar!" />
```

Comment: O problema é que não dá pra colocar links na emptyMessage do autoComplete. O que eu sugiro é que nessa situação você renderize um link fora, abaixo do autocomplete, por exemplo. Daria certo assim pra você?

Comment: Acredito que sim, mas como eu faria para saber se a busca no AutoComplete retornou resultados ou não, para que assim possa renderizar ou não o link?